# QR-Code with google chart API - Invalid for google authenticator app

Tags: java, authentication, qr-code

> **Warning:**  sharing your TOTP seed with third-parties breaks the very basic assumption of multi-factor authentication that the TOTP
>   seed is *secret*.

I generated a secret `EBWFBWYCPPELHQS5` and I can add it manually to the Google Authenticator App.

But if I generate a QR-Code from this secret via the google chart API, I can not scan the QR-Code, the app tells me the QR-code is not valid. 
This would be the QR-code for the secret above:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/test@test&secret=EBWFBWYCPPELHQS5

My code to generate the url looks like this:

```
public static String getQRBarcodeURL(String user, String host, String secret) {
    return "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?" + getQRBarcodeURLQuery(user, host, secret);
}

public static String getQRBarcodeURLQuery(String user, String host, String secret) {
    return "chs=200x200&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chl=" +
            getQRBarcodeOtpAuthURL(user, host, secret);
}

public static String getQRBarcodeOtpAuthURL(String user, String host, String secret) {
    return String.format("otpauth://totp/%s@%s&secret=%s", user, host, secret);
}
```

How can I get this working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [URL Encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the data that you send to the Google Charts API.

The `&` character should be `%26`  like so:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/test@test%26secret=EBWFBWYCPPELHQS5

Otherwise, the API thinks everything after the `&` is another parameter for it, rather than data to be encoded.

Comment: Actually the `secret` is the first query parameter, so the `%26` (`&`) should actually be `%3F` (`?`) - subsequent params should be separated with `%26` (`&`).

Comment: @Terence Eden
Is it possible that all of those qr code for OTP are using google charts API to generate the qr code? I mean can we make our own self hosted thing? If yes, would you please share some links?